# Angular compilation fails

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I was following some video tutorial from angular university. When I run ng serve/ npm start, it fails but if I just re-save any file just by adding/removing blank,it compiles successfully.Please find following screenshot:[image]

```
My Package.json:

{
  "name": "reactive-patterns-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "rest-api": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/server/server.ts",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.52",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "firebase": "^3.7.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cookies-js": "^1.2.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",

        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
      }
    }

Could someone help me on this.I did run NPM update but of no avail.I have Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.10.0
```

I am not using any Generic type here.Even if someone uses it, it should fail all the time. Please find app-data file following.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Lesson} from '../shared/model/lesson';


export interface Observer {
    next(data: any);
}

export interface Observable {
  subscribe(obs: Observer);
  unsubscribe(obs: Observer);
}

interface Subject extends Observer, Observable {
}

    class  SubjectImplementation implements Subject {

      private observers: Observer[] = [];

      next(data: any) {
        this.observers.forEach(obs => obs.next(data));
      }

      subscribe(obs: Observer) {
        this.observers.push(obs);
      }

      unsubscribe(obs: Observer) {
        _.remove(this.observers, el => el === obs);
      }
    }

    const lessonsListSubject=new SubjectImplementation();

    export let lessonList$: Observable = {
      subscribe: obs => lessonsListSubject.subscribe(obs),
      unsubscribe: obs => lessonsListSubject.unsubscribe(obs)

    };

    let lessons: Lesson[] = [];

    export function initializeLessonsList(newList: Lesson[]) {
      lessons = _.cloneDeep(newList);
      lessonsListSubject.next(lessons);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the `Observable<T>` type without specific the type for the generic. Can you provide your `app-data.ts` file so we can help you fix these issues?

Comment: sure adding it my question details.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement all of these things provided by the rxjs library?? And yeah, when you use the rxjs observable you need to specify the generic parameter on it.

Comment: I am trying to understand the pattern first as I am noob here later  I am planning to use RxJx, as it helps me to understand the library/utility better way.Thanks a lot Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very self-explanatory (and even shows the file and line number where the error sits - `app-data.ts(15,37)`) - Observable is a generic type and requires one type. So you can not set someones type as Observable without Observable's type. So this is **not valid** - `someVar: Observable`.

In your code replace `export let lessonList$: Observable = {` with `export let lessonList$: Observable<any> = {` or a specific type which this Observable will stream.